# how to make botton over single image in android

Tags: android, image, button

I have requirement of adding button behind single image. My main.xml is mentioned below. I am trying to create button3 for abcimage as shown below. I want this button at left center. How it can be done?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2_Left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/abcimage"></ImageView>
            <Button
          android:id="@+id/button3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text="buyabc" 
        /> 
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just use a `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView2_Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abcimage" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="buyabc" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FrameLayout` which contains your image and your button:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView2_Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/abcimage" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="buyabc" />
</FrameLayout>
```